# how to have a button build a widget and have it setstate

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I currently have a InkWell that builds a custom widget alert dialog when pressed using the build method below.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () => showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => Popup(),
```

I also need it to set the state of some Bools and Int's when pressed which usually happens when using the setstate method.
can someone please show me how to do both build a widget and setstate when the button is pressed?
what would the code look like?

cheers

Comment: You can call put both `setState` and `showDialog` inside `onTap()`. 

`onTap: () { setState(); showDialog<String>(); }`

Comment: Can you include more snippet that will reproduce the issue

Comment: legend! thanks so much! was putting the bracket in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function and set bools before you build the dialog. Then call the method in onTap:

```
buildMyDialog(){
  myBool = false;
  myInt = 2;
  showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => Popup(),
  );
}
```

If you need your current UI to use the values, setState before showing dialog in the same method.